# jquery ajax not Sending data back to JSP via Spring Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I am trying to make an ajax call to a Java method (returns a String) via Spring MVC. This javascript code below successfully calls the Java method and prints what I expect to the eclipse console. I am trying to output the text I just mentioned on my html page. My problem is that neither the success or error callback functions are even entered so obviously I cannot get to the information returned by the Java method.

Thanks in advance

```
$("#dateButton").click(function(e){

            fromdate = $("input#fromdate").val();
            todate = $("input#todate").val();
            fromcurr = $("input#fromcurr").val();

            tocurr = $("input#tocurr").val();

            var dataString = "fromdate=" +fromdate+"&todate="+todate+"&fromcurr="+fromcurr+"&tocurr="+tocurr;
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "getDailyRates.html",
                data: dataString,
                datatype: "text",
                async: 'false',
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    alert("in success");
                    $('#display').html("");

                    $('#display').append(data);
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert("ERROR!");
                }
            });



        });
```

Java method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getDailyRates.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getDailyRates(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) {

        DailyRatesQuery dailyRate= new DailyRatesQuery();
        String fromCurr= request.getParameter("fromcurr");
        String toCurr= request.getParameter("tocurr"); 
        String fromDate= request.getParameter("fromdate"); 
        String toDate=request.getParameter("todate");

        dailyRate.setFromCurr(fromCurr);
        dailyRate.setToCurr(toCurr);
        dailyRate.setFromDate(fromDate);
        dailyRate.setToDate(toDate);


        System.out.println("From Currency: "+fromCurr+" To Currency: "+toCurr+
                " fromDate: "+fromDate+" toDate: "+toDate);


        List<DailyRate> rates = jdbcRateDao.getDailyRates(dailyRate);


        System.out.println("Before return new model");
        System.out.println(rates.toString());
        return rates.get(0).toString();

    }
```

UPDATE:

When I click the button the JavaScript function is mapped to, The Java method I have posted is successfully called and generates the correct output. It is just no sending that output back to my JSP.

Comment: Note, `async: 'false'` is exactly the same as `async: true` and `datatype` should be `dataType`, but neither are related to your issue.

Comment: If you aren't getting success or error callbacks, then you are either doing JSONP(which you aren't) or the ajax request isn't being sent in the first place. Look for errors in your javascript console and confirm that the click event is even being called.

Comment: Ok, now its at least calling the error function. But it should still go into success. The error message Firebug gives me is
POST getDailyRates.html 404 Not found. 

I know this is because that is a virtual url and doesnt exist. The method being called by the virtual url just returns a String and it does that succesfully through the ajax call. For some reason the ajax call is not receiving the the returned String.

Comment: If it's giving you 404, that's why it's reaching the error. the status code must indicate success.

Comment: I understand that. I just don't understand why I am getting the 404 error. It had to have found the html in order to have even called the Java method in the first place. It should still be able to find it now.

Comment: if you create an html form and post it manually, do you get the string you're expecting?

Comment: I am not sure what that means. The problem seems to be when my java method is returning the String, it does not know where to send it. I'll post the Java code.

Comment: Kyle - did you ever solve this issue?   I have the same problem.  When my JQuery AJAX call is fired,  my controller method executes properly...--but the server still returns a "NOT FOUND"...

Comment: you need to add @ResponseBody to your getDailyRates method